# Can't get these elements to be perfectly aligned and equally heighted in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I've  been screwing around with this for almost 2 hours and still can't get it to render the right way in Microsoft Outlook.

It was enough of a pain to get it to render in Internet Explorer, but I got it:

[image]

Still, here's how it looks as an HTML email in Outlook:

[image]

Don't worry about the line break for now; the problems I need to fix are

(1) The 1 pixel of white vertical space between the left piece and center piece

(2) The center piece having pixel more height than the left and right pieces

Here's the HTML:

```
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="6" height="35">
                        <img src="images/left-button-corner.png" style="display:block;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="center" bgcolor="#0a9fda" style="padding: 0 10px;" width="220" height="35">
                        <a href="http://img03.en25.com/EloquaImages/clients/SeagateCSS/{87374fad-7bdb-478e-a8e0-7b50f37e1aaf}_btnDownload.png" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE</a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left"  width="6">
                        <img src="images/right-button-corner.png" style="display:block;" height="35"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

If I can't get it, I'm going to give up and use a single image. Any input much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following.

Try `align="right"` on the left button image:

```
<td align="right" width="6" height="35">
    <img src="images/left-button-corner.png" style="display:block;"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the height issue.

The height of the middle `td` is the content height (in this case it is `line-height`) + `padding-top` + `padding-bottom`.

You can remove `padding` declaration and `valign` and `width` attributes to make text vertically aligned to the middle and your button will be scaling horizontally (no breaks). I assume that would be good choice, considering you coded fixed height value of 35px.

#### Example of the middle `<td>`:

```html
<td align="center" bgcolor="#0a9fda" style="height: 35px;" height="35">
    <a href="http://example.com" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px;
                                        font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none;">
      CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE</a>
</td>
```

#### Additional Notes

- You can control how the call-to-action text should break by using `&nbsp;` entity. For example `CLICK&nbsp;HERE TO&nbsp;LEARN&nbsp;MORE` will break after "HERE" if the `td width` is insufficient to fit the text in one line.
- Images should have `border: none` inline style to prevent uncontrolled gaps.
- Also note, that `valign` attribute value `center` is incorrect. It can have values of `top`, `bottom`, or `middle` which is default.
- There are more issues with your code.
  Validate your code with some tool, for example http://validator.w3.org/.